# Is there an alternative to carbonite?

Tags: software-recommendation, backup

Can anyone tell be if there is an alternative to carbonite for ubuntu.

I love the idea of carbonite's "unlimited" automatic backup, can anyone help

Cheers

Comment: I've never used Carbonite. But have you looked into Deja Dup? Which allows you to backup the files to Rackspace Files, a separate partition, disk drive, or even to Amazon Cloud?

Answer (score 4):

Both [Spideroak](https://www.spideroak.com) and [Crashplan](http://www.crashplan.com) have a linux clients.

Comment: +1: I didn't know about Crashplan. Anyone got any experience with them?

Comment: For anyone visiting now: I got great experience with Crashplan, **however**, they are going to shutdown their products for home users.

Comment: Disappointing that Crashplan recommends Carbonite which does not support Linux at this time https://www.crashplan.com/en-us/consumer/nextsteps/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@daithib8](https://askubuntu.com/users/10837/daithib8), I agree with and have chosen [**SpiderOak**](https://www.spideroak.com/) personally.

For additional supporting evidence from Leo Laporte and Steve Gibson, please see Security Now Episode 349 [video](https://twit.tv/shows/security-now/episodes/349) or [transcript](https://www.grc.com/sn/sn-349.htm).